# How to replace switch with Object literals

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, discord.js, switch-statement

When i rewriting my old code, i had a problem i don't know to to optimize this code in past i use switch,but now i know about Object literals, my code:

```js
switch(true) {
 case data.rep <= -30:
    reputation_text = this.language.pf.reputation.satan;
    break;
 case data.rep >= -10 && data.rep <= -5:
    reputation_text = this.language.pf.reputation.devil;
    break;
 //other....

 case data.rep >= 30:
 reputation_text = this.language.pf.reputation.angel;
 break;
}
```

How i can replace him with object literals?

Comment: Why aren't you using if-else? This is not what switch cases are used for

Comment: I think that that's a really fascinating use of `switch`. I will use it some time in the future.

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: @adiga, ok, i edit now

Comment: @adiga its good?

Comment: You are missing a -30 to -10 range in the `switch`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @adiga srry,no, i accidentally

Comment: @Wang's answer is pretty good. I added a comment there if you want to simplify it a but by checking only the upper limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the cases as object literals and iterate over them:

```js
const { reputations } = this.language.pf;

type MapEntry = { min: number; max: number; value: keyof typeof reputations };

const mapTable: MapEntry[] = [
  { min: Number.MIN_VALUE, max: -30, 
    value: "satan" },
  { min: -10, max: -5, 
    value: "devil" },
  // ...
  { min: 30, max: Number.MAX_VALUE, 
    value: "angel" },
];

for (const entry of mapTable) {
  if (Data.rep >= entry.min && Data.rep <= entry.max) {
    reputation_text = reputations[entry.value];
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can add a `break` inside the `if` condition to exit early

Comment: You can probably simplify the answer by adding only the `max` value. OP confirmed there is a value for -30 to -10.

Comment: You could also use `find` to get the object:`[{ limit: -30, value: 'satan' }, etc]`. And then: `let { value } = mapTable.find(v => data.rep <= v.limit); reputation_text = reputations[value]`